# how to set duration of audio array depending on user's select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make my code play an array of audio files but when my index i = 4, the duration would depend on user's select tag. I tired to catch user's option by select name and multiply 100 (because it's millisecond). My program shows it's undefined. Why is it?

And After entire array has been played in the first round, my code would repeat playing audio from array playlist element 3 to 5 but it's random chosen. I was thinking to use random seed to pick the element from 3 to 5. But this is math involved. How should I approach this?

Thank you for you help. I appreciate it

```
<select id="numFollowUp" name="numFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Number of follow-up questions</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="secFollowUp" name="secFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Second between each question</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
        </select>

var intro_playList = [{
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "0_silence"
    }, {
        "duration": 500,
        "key": "1_hello"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "2_how_old"
    }, {
        "duration": 1000,
        "key": "3_what_did_you_make"
    }, {
        "duration": document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000,
        "key": "4_tell_me_a_story"
    }, {
        "duration": document.getElementById("secFollowUp").value * 1000,
        "key": "5_and_then_what"
    }];

  var i = 0;

  $("#play").on("click", playAudio);

        function playAudio() {
            var audioIndex = intro_playList[i++];
            console.log(audioIndex);
            console.log("After " + audioIndex.duration + " seconds play next audio");

            audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
            audioElement.load();
            setTimeout(function() { audioElement.play()}, audioIndex.duration);

            if(i === 4){

                audioElement.src = "sound/" + audioIndex.key + ".wav";
                audioElement.load();
                setTimeout(function(){ audioElement.play()}, select_value);

                $("#numFollowUp").change(function(){
                    $(this).val() = repeat;
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because `document.getElementsByName("secFollowUp")` returns a NodeList and not a specific element.

So if `secFollowUp` is indeed the name of an input element (*and you want to access it with the `getElementsByName` method*) you must use `document.getElementsByName("secFollowUp")[0].value` (*notice the `[0]` to get the 1st element of the NodeList*)

If it is the `id` of the `input` element then use `document.getElementById('secFollowUp').value`

***update***
Had not noticed the actual html in your post, both solutions will work but the second is better (using the `getElementById`)

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, Gaby. I will give it a shot and let you know if I have any further questions. It will probably tonight or tomorrow night. I gotta deal with moving and car issues first.

Comment: Thank you Gaby. It's working. If I have a specific element I wanna access, then I can use document.getElementsById("secFollowUp")[0].value in my array list just like what you suggested. But I need to make it depend on user's selection. Thus, I did document.getElementsById("secFollowUp").value in my array list. But it always gave me 0 second, why is this?

Comment: I have figured out my problem. But yours answer is helpful as well. I should give you the best answer.